# Ontology editor for CLIPS applications

Tags: ontology, expert-system, clips

What GUI-based ontology editors are there that can export ontologies to CLIPS format?  I am aware of [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/) but some CLIPS language features are not supported and the associated CLIPSTab plugin appears to be stagnant (no updates in about 9 years).  Are there any other ontology editors that integrate well with CLIPS?  I am specifically looking for a graphical tool for creating/editing class hierarchies, slots, instances, etc.

Comment: I'm using Protege 3.1.1 and It's fine, except we have to add a little bit code... I'm interested in alternatives too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say there really isn't anything "out of the box" that works.

Because expert systems (and AI in general) is so dominated by academia (where there is no money to be made) very few people (companies) expend the resources to make good tools.